# What is the intended use case of a RadAjaxManager w/ Ajax requests versus an UpdatePanel/RadAjaxPanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, updatepanel

I'm confused at the benefits of using RadAjaxManager with Ajax requests versus using and UpdatePanel/RadAjaxPanel.
I have both in my solution and it is creating some havoc. What design methodologies are typically deemed best (a bit subjective I realize)

Should I only perform data operations using Ajax and all GUI updates using UpdatePanels/RadAjaxPanels?

Currently I am sometimes updating controls via Ajax manager triggered by ajax request and sometimes a control will postback entirely. If I decide to do everything via Ajax, do I have to make sure nothing ever posts back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check official [statement](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/radcontrols-in-dotnetnuke/updatepanel-vs-radajaxpanel-quot-lazy-ajax-quot.aspx). I think that mixing MS Ajax with Telerik is not a good idea.